# No such module error when using bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging

I created a sample app, and added an Objective-C class called "TestFile".

[image]

My bridging header simply says,

```
#import "TestFile.h"
```

And my view controller includes an import statement:

[image]

Why am I getting an error message saying `No such module 'TestFile'?` This is the most basic setup possible, why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 10):

You should not `import` it since it is not any module, just a objective-C file. So you can directly use your class in your code like:

```
let testFile = TestFile()
```